# How to capture the svn authentication prompt on powershell console

Tags: svn, powershell, tortoisesvn

I am trying to download from subversion. I am able to catch the error message and success message. However, I want to capture any prompt that command gives me such as username and pasword on the console which I am unable to do so in the current scenario. Please help.
Code:

```
$msg=svn --force export $SVN[$i] 2>&1 
if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 1)
{
    "Encountered error during SVN Checkout. Error Message is $msg. Please check." >> $LogFile
    exit
}

$msg >> $LogFile
```

Comment: By "capture", do you mean you want to log the prompt?

Comment: Are you looking for [`Start-Transcript`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff687007.aspx)?

Comment: when I execute the svn export command, it should prompt me for user id and password if the credentials stored in cache does not have privileges. in the current scenario, it is not prompting. it waits for sometime and then exits.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to login to SVN from your script, there are a couple of alternatives. One is to script the input to SVN and to pipe the input into SVN:

```
$msg=svn --force export $SVN[$i] 2>&1 <scripted_svn_input.txt
```

However I'm guessing that you want to supply *unscripted* input to SVN. In that case you can pipe output from SVN to the PS console and pipe input from the PS console into SVN. Here is a mostly complete example of this here: [How to run interactive commands in another application window from powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17205091/how-to-run-interactive-commands-in-another-application-window-from-powershell/17254421#17254421)