# VB equivalent to powershell

Tags: powershell

I am very new to `powershell` and sometimes this question may be so simple

Can please anybody please tell me what is the equivalent to the following(vbscript) in PowerShell

```
set obj = wscript.createobject( wscript.shell )  
Obj.Run $smCmnd
```

What is the use of `wscript.shell`.
After a bit of search I found first line can be presented as;

```
$obj  = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
```

But have have no idea how to call Run method (**$obj.run(...)**???)

If I run `cmd.exe` with some commands as the `smCmnd`, How can I keep cmd.exe without close and to run another command later in same console??

**EDIT**
I am writing `PS script` and it will be call from another application. Basically it will do some folder creations and file coping etc. I would like to open CMD.exe and show all the commands running on that. How to use same cmd prompt through out my whole script.

Comment: Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. What do you want to achieve by running CMD from PowerShell?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - I would like to show the what is happening to the user

Comment: You could use `Start-Transcript` and display the generated file in a pager as it's written.

Answer (score 1):

Is smCmnd a string of shell commands?  If so, you can call them directly from PowerShell, without trying to get a wscript.shell COM object to run them against like you'd need to do in VBScript.

VBScript wasn't a shell.  Powershell is.  You can write shell commands directly in .ps1 or .ps2 files, just like in a batch file.

I'm not a powershell expert here, but try doing

```
& $smCmnd
```

Comment: What is the exact use of wscript.shell

Comment: I have added some information to my question. Is it possible to open cmd and send different commands for it time to time in PS like Vb does

Comment: There is no use of `WScript.Shell` in PowerShell. There's no need for it.

Comment: @NewDeveloper - Your question is mutating now.  I suggest writing a new one, and explaining what you're trying to do more clearly.  Just ask about the CMD exe part - don't talk about wscript.shell.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `$smCmnd` directly. If that fails, use `Invoke-Expression $smCmnd`.

Comment: I am writing PS script and it will be call from another application. Basically it will do some folder creations and file coping etc. I would like to open CMD.exe and show all the commands running on that. How to use same cmd prompt through out my whole script

Comment: Don't use CMD when you're using PowerShell. I mentioned that before, didn't I?

Answer (score 0):

If you do need to use CMD.EXE (possibly because you want to run pre-existing BAT file), and you want all of the output in a single CMD window you can pipe all the input into cmd at once like this:

```
# Powershell script to execute existing BAT file
cmd.exe /k "cd c:\batchfiles & firstone.bat & second.bat & echo that's all folks"
# CMD will remain open (/k). User will have to type exit to return to powershell

# Or if you want user just to hit any key to leave CMD prompt:
cmd.exe /c "c:\batchfiles\mybatchfile.bat & pause"
# /C means CMD should close after is has executed the commands on the command line
```

However if you want to have something execute in CMD, then make a decision in your Powershell script about what to execute next in CMD then do something similar to the answer at the following link which pipes input and output between a powershell script and CMD.exe.

[How to run interactive commands in another application window from powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17205091/how-to-run-interactive-commands-in-another-application-window-from-powershell/17254421#17254421)