# Launch external program with multiple commands via Powershell

Tags: powershell, docker, sh, docker-compose

I am currently attempting to launch a different console (.exe) and pass multiple commands; while starting and entering a command works just fine, I haven't been able to find out how multiple ones can be entered via powershell.

```
& "C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\start.sh" docker-compose up -d --build
```

The given command works fine, but as mentioned I need to pass more than one command - I tried using arrays, ScriptBlocks and different sequences, though to no avail.

**Edit**:

Noticed that the `docker build` has a -f tag which allows me to specify a file; however, the issue now seems to be that the executed cmd removes all backslashes & special characters, rendering the path given useless.

Example:

```
&"C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\start.sh" 'docker-compose build -f 
path\to\dockerfile'
```

will result in an error stating that `"pathtodockerfile"` is an invalid path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it was easier than expected; Solved it by executing a seperate file that contained the two commands needed and passing it to the start.sh file.

```
&"C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\start.sh" './xyz/fileContainingCommands.sh'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `start.sh` needs to be able to handle multiple arguments.  This doesn't look like a PowerShell question

Comment: How'd I find out? start.sh is the file provided by Docker, and I have to run it as it configures all necessary proxy & VM settings.

Comment: @AscendedKitten Try quoting the arguments as a single string.  `& 'C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\start.sh' 'docker-compose up -d --build'`

Comment: the arguments aren't the issue, as they are recognized - the issue lies in executing multiple commands, since I need to navigate to the right directory using cd before using docker-compose.

Comment: @AscendedKitten So you're trying to use PowerShell to send commands to a different program's console?

Comment: Exactly. Basically the rest of the script downloads some stuff, and in the end calls the program that actually processes that data. Though I do need more than one command to initialize that.

Comment: @AscendedKitten I'm not sure if that's possible.  Here's a similar question I found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17205091/how-to-run-interactive-commands-in-another-application-window-from-powershell

Comment: Quite sure it is. Thanks for the link, but the answers all seem to be over-complicated for my case, considering that all I need is the ability to run two commands instead of 1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148425/discussion-between-theincorrigible1-and-ascendedkitten).