# proper way to prevent powershell script from closing console immediately after execution

Tags: windows, powershell, automation

I have automated some of my backup routines using power-shell scripts. What can I do to make sure the console stays open for maybe 5 seconds after execution completes so that I can read whatever feedback is provided and verify that there weren't any unexpected errors?

Comment: `start-sleep 5` or you could use `read-host`, then it would only end if you hit enter

Comment: Launch `powershell.exe` with the `-noexit` switch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will work in most cases, but, as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17254421/4190564), it does not work in Windows PowerShell ISE.

```
function Pause {
    Write-Host -NoNewLine 'Press any key to continue . . .';
    $null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown');
}
```

This closely mimics the the `PAUSE` command in the Windows command prompt.  Simply place the following line where ever you want the code to pause for the user to view information.

```
Pause
```