# Can we call Bat command within powershell without calling/invoking a bat file?

Tags: bash, powershell, batch-file, command

Can we call Bat command within powershell without calling/invoking a bat file?

For example bat script:

```
@echo [off]
echo sample batch script
pause
```

In powershell itself

Commands must be executed.

Comment: Batch commands aren't powershell commands (there are a few overlapping aliases, but the commands themselves are different), so I'm not sure what you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 2):

You can emulate most things BATCH.

1. For example [`PAUSE`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74142646/4190564).
2. And `ECHO` is similar to `Write-Host` and `$Var | Out-Host`.

Also, you can call BATCH commands with [`cmd.exe --% /c`](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html), **BUT**, as soon as cmd.exe exits, the environment the command was executed in is gone - along with any environment variables that were set.

On the other hand, `cmd.exe`'s output can be saved to a variable.
In this example:

1. Everything after the [Stop-Parsing token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-5.1#the-stop-parsing-token) is passed unprocessed to CMD.
2. The path given to `dir` is dynamically provided by first setting an environment variable `$Env:DirPath = 'C:\Users\public'`, and then retrieved the environment variable in BATCH `%DirPath%`.
3. Uses `$Var = $(<code>)` to save output in $Var.

**NOTE:** The closing parentheses is **NOT** at the end of the `cmd.exe --%` line, because, if it was, it would be ignored by PowerShell.

```
$Env:DirPath = 'C:\Users\public'
$Var = $(
    cmd.exe --% /c dir "%DirPath%" /w
)
$Var
```

You should also be able to use `&` in the `cmd.exe --%` command to execute more than one BATCH command, but I haven't experimented with that, so not sure how that would work out.

Comment: Nicely done, but I suggest also mentioning `Write-Output`, not just `Write-Host`, in the context of `echo`.
Note that while there are indeed many pitfalls with `--%`, a single-line `$Var = cmd.exe --% /c dir "%DirPath%" /w` would work fine.
If you enclose everything after `/c` in `'...'`, you can avoid `--%` (except for potentially needing to escape embedded `'` as `''`, 
but even that can be avoided with a _here-string_). Similarly,  `cmd /c "..."` allows direct use of PowerShell's string interpolation
(though this mixing of the worlds may be harder to understand)

Answer (score 1):

- **You *cannot* execute batch-file commands *directly* in PowerShell**, because PowerShell doesn't understand them.

  - While there is a *small subset* of commands that have the same name in both `cmd.exe` (the interpreter of batch files) and PowerShell, by way of PowerShell providing *aliases* for its differently named commands (e.g., `dir` for `Get-ChildItem`), calls to these few commands only work the same in all but the simplest cases, given that PowerShell's parameter syntax differs fundamentally from that of `cmd.exe`
- **You *can* execute batch-file commands via `cmd.exe`'s CLI**, namely either via **`cmd /c`** (run `cmd /?` for details) or by ***piping* commands to `cmd.exe`** (`... | cmd`),  but note the following:

  - Like batch files, such calls run in a *child* process, so that modifications to environment variables wouldn't be seen by the caller, for instances.
  - The **commands are interpreted as in *interactive* `cmd.exe` sessions**, which notably means that `for` loops must use `%i` rather than `%%i`, for instance.
  - **Passing *multiple* batch-file commands has *severe limitations***:

    - **With `cmd /c`**, you **can only pass a *single* line** (any additional lines are ignored), so you must use `cmd.exe`'s `&` operator to sequence multiple commands, which only works *if these commands do not depend on each other with respect to variables*.

      ```
       # OK - the two commands aren't interdependent.
       cmd /c 'ver & date /t'

       # !! NOT OK - the %FOO% value isn't seen by the echo call
       cmd /c '(Set FOO=bar) & echo %FOO%'
      ```

      - However, you can enable the delayed-variable-expansion feature via the `/v` option, in which case using `!...!` instead of `%...%` *does* work:

        ```
         # OK - thanks to /v and !FOO!
         cmd /v /c '(Set FOO=bar) & echo !FOO!'
        ```
      - Separately, you can use an [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) in order to embed the value of *PowerShell* variables in the `cmd /c`  call, as an alternative to the `--%` technique shown in [Darin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76005098/45375); if you need to embed `"` characters, escape them as `` `" `` (or `""`):

        ```
         $foo = 'bar' # define a PowerShell variable
         cmd /c "echo $foo" # embed its value in the "..." string
        ```
    - **With multiline pipeline input**:

      - **Even if you start your multiline input string with `@echo off`, you will invariably see `cmd.exe`'s *startup banner* ( `Microsoft Windows [Version ...]`) and *one* prompt string (e.g, `C:\>`), and the *source code line of each command will print* either way before the result of its execution.**
      - Unless the code exits with an explicit `exit` call, the `cmd.exe`'s exit code will *not* reflect the exit code of the last command executed.
      - For more information as well as a helper function that creates a *temporary batch file* behind the scenes to avoid these limitations, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39948297/45375)
      - Here's an example that uses a [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings) to feed multiple commands to `cmd.exe`; as noted, you'll see the startup banner and one prompt string, and the source-code lines will print before each command's output:

        ```
         @'
         @echo off
         ver
         date /t
         Set FOO=bar
         echo %FOO%
         exit
         '@ | cmd.exe
        ```