# Is there a Unix Expect Binary / Utility equivalent for Windows Batch or Powershell for interactive scripts?

Tags: linux, windows, powershell, automation, expect

I am trying mirror a process on Windows that I use on linux for creating an automated build of an application web server. The only way to have full automation is to have some sort of EXPECT utility for the interactions on the CLI.

We use a script to setup all the configuration and settings for our applications web servers that is easily portable to batch since the web server is windows compatible as well with the same commands.

I've basically got it down for Linux, however the flip side to this is that the windows doesn't seem to have a clear expect alternative.

Any suggestions to allow it to send a response when prompted and continue the rest of the scripted process would be most helpful.

Comment: Any do you need an alternative for expect, expect is available for windows: https://www.activestate.com/products/activetcl/

Comment: Is there any open source type? We are trying to make a headless installer.

Comment: You could install WSL, say the Ubuntu flavour, and then `apt` install expect.

Comment: Might be answered by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800368/equivalent-to-bash-expect-in-powershell or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27808546/windows-expect-command-equivalent .